# React errors without even doing any thing

Tags: reactjs

1. I created a new `React` app
2. I started the `React` app with npm start
3. I press enter to write code and all I get is the tags are getting separated and tons of errors showing up the cause of the self-closing tags.

PS: I literally didn't do anything else

Comment: Can you provide a playground /or code of what you tried and how you created your app.

Comment: with the command  npx create react app